# Cross Origin error with window.fetch() on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest, cors, fetch

I'm trying to use the window.fetch API and along with a Polyfill for unsupporting browsers.

My code works in both Chrome and Firefox, but is failing in Safari (all on Mac OSX).

```
function signup(fullname, email, restaurant, source) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = `cm-name=${encodeURIComponent(fullname)}&cm-ottdth-ottdth=${encodeURIComponent(email)}&cm-f-hykuuh=${encodeURIComponent(restaurant)}&cm-f-hyurjd=${encodeURIComponent(source)}`;
    fetch(`http://tastyplc.createsend.com/t/d/s/ottdth/?${params}`, {
      method: 'get',
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => resolve(data))
    .catch(error => reject(Error(error)));
  });
}
```

I get the following error in Safari:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://tastyplc.createsend.com/t/d/s/ottdth/?cm-name=example&cm-ottdth-ottdth=example%40example.com&cm-f-hykuuh=Charlotte%20Street&cm-f-hyurjd=Website%20Sign%20Up.
>   Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Could this be something related to the polyfill being used - since it mentions **XMLHttpRequest** (which I'm assuming the polyfill falls-back to).

https://github.com/github/fetch

Anything I'm doing wrong or missing? It's driving me nuts.

Thanks!

Comment: check the safari's n/w and proxy settings if its matching with Chrome and firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is working in either Chrome or Firefox because [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode), when you set the `mode` to `'no-cors'` "JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response." So are you actually getting data back from the resolved promise in Chrome/Firefox? If you simply want to make a GET request w/o having access to the response data then you could just create an `<img>` element, set its `src` attribute to your URL and append it to the DOM.

Comment: Almost two years later, did you find any solution to this?